# how to install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf 4.9 on ubuntu 22.04 for arm 32 bit

Tags: kernel, compiling, 22.04, gcc, arm

I'm running ubuntu 22.04 for arm32 on my arm chromebook snow :

```
mario@changeme:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# uname -a
Linux changeme 5.18.1-stb-cbe+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jun 5 14:16:07 CEST 2022 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

mario@changeme:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

I would like to know how can I install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf version 4 (maybe the 4.9 is good) on that os because I want to recompile the kernel 3.3 because it wants that. thanks.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu in the ARM Chromebook?

Comment: https://github.com/hexdump0815/linux-mainline-on-arm-chromebooks/issues/3#issuecomment-1450800478

Comment: It would be great if you write a question-answer post about how to install Ubuntu on an ARM Chromebook. I wrote one for Intel Chromebooks https://askubuntu.com/q/1468964/124466

Comment: my project was to update the kernel of ubuntu on the chromebook arm with the goal to enable kvm. Unfortunately I failed to reach this goal. Please contact me on marietto2008@gmail.com,let's talk about this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer for your specific architecture (arm32 chromebook), but this worked on my arm64 MacBook:

I added Xenial (16.04) to my apt sources:

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial universe
```

This old version of Ubuntu contains the GCC in version 4.9:

```sh
$ apt policy gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabi
gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabi:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1
  Version table:
     4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe arm64 Packages
```

For GCC version 5, I didn't have to go that far, Ubuntu Bionic (18.04) had these packages.